# JSF 2.0 and Richfaces configuration

Tags: jsf, maven, richfaces

I'm new in Richfaces framework. In this time I'm trying to add this to my engineering project. Unfortunately have a lot of problem with making this framework running with JSF 2.0 . I've tried to download a lot of maven archetypes but most of them aren't working. Could you point me the place where I can find something like JSF 2.0 + Richfaces 4 blank and configured project? It can be maven as well. I've spend all day today to make it running but things are so complex for me in this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need much. You probably need the reposity for the dependencies, the plugin to build the war file, a JSF version (I assume that your container supplies a JSF api+implementation, thus `provided`), and RichFaces API + implementation.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.your.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>your.project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</project.build.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>JBoss repository</name>
            <!-- <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url> -->
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.22</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```